# NU1001 The dependency Microsoft...>=1.0.0 could not be resolved

Tags: json, asp.net-core

my Problem is:

Today i open my App in Visual Studio 2015 but there was an ERROR by the References about:

- NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore >= 1.0.0 could be resolved.
- NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions >= 1.0.0 could be resolved.

What can I do to remove this problem ?

Here is a Image of that what i see:

[The failure data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsfpM.png)

Comment: Did you try and restore again using References -> Restore Packages or `dotnet restore`?

Comment: i try it now, i ask if it does not work after that

Comment: ok, Henk Mollema, it is working now, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like Visual Studio is upset. You can try and force a restore of your packages via:

References -> Restore Packages

Or run:

```
dotnet restore
```

on the command line

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking on References, and restoring packages may fix the problem.

If the solution still builds, and the error is only seen via resharper/red errors for intellisense in visual studio, it may be another problem which appears to be related to the order the dependencies are processed.

Go to your **project.json**, and if you see red lines under the versions here, your problem will be the ordering.  Hover over the red line to show "potential fixes", and select "**sort dependencies**".

(NB: this is likely a bug in either VS or resharper, but worth noting.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the Dot Net core preview tool from the version 1.0.0 to version 1.0.1 version
Then you have to restore the packages.